# Can I download the current version of QGIS if I am running Mac 10.8.2?

Tags: qgis, mac

I am taking an introductory course in GIS at my university and my teacher recommended QGIS for Mac users. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to download the software. I just upgraded to Mac OS 10.8.2 recently, and I am not sure if Lisboa can work on Mountain Lion. Please let me know what I need to do in order to run QGIS on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis (as described above) and download the following - my list are the minimal requirements to run QGis on 10.8.2 ML.

1. GDAL_Complete-1.9.dmg
2. GSL_Framework-1.15-2.dmg
3. QGIS-1.8.0-2.dmg

Open the .dmg´s and install it in the given order (at point 1 use only the installer GDAL complete installer (can´t remember the exact name).

If Gatekeeper say you are not allowed to install this software go to Systempreferences => Security and change the settings for the moment. During the above installation you are prompted 3 times for your Admin password. At the end you will find a new icon (the yellow Q) in your application folder (it is also available using Launchpad).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Kyng Chaos builds:

http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: These worked fine for me on Mountain Lion.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed each of those files multiple times in the past couple days of working on this but I cannot find it in my applications or anywhere else to actually run the program.

Comment: Many are frameworks.  For example: `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/`  QGIS will install as an application though.